# why we give reference to the other projects?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, inheritance, reference, namespaces

When looking at a solution with multiple projects:

1) Why do we add a reference to the other project? Can't we just use inheritance?

2) After we add the reference by using Visual Studio, why do we have to add the project to the namespace system? For example: `using myReferenceProject;` I thought that the IDE would do that.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using myReferenceProject;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
```

Comment: one question mark will do just fine :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> 1) why we give reference to the other project? cant we just use inheritance???

They're two *completely* different concepts.

Adding a reference to another assembly basically says, "I want to be able to use some of this code. Please make the compiler aware that this code exists, and optionally copy it into the output directory so that it's present at execution time too."

How would you expect to use inheritance to create a class derived from some type if the compiler has no knowledge of that type?

> 2) after we give the reference by using the visual studio IDE why we have to add the project to the namespace system???

Because assemblies and namespaces are different concepts too. A `using` directive simply says to the compiler "When I refer to type `Foo` within my code, look in these namespaces to try to resolve it." That type could come from *any* of the assemblies you've referenced.

It's really important that you understand the difference between assemblies and namespaces. Even though they're *often* named similarly (`Foo.Bar.dll` often provides types in the namespace `Foo.Bar`) they're *conceptually* different.

Comment: Dear Jon; your answer to the 1st question reminded me the concept of header file. for example  #include .... in c++. but not made my mind Cristal clear if its really related with header files or has someway connections or similarities with adding a reference. i thought that if i inherit the class then i can use in my project and can create objects. for the answer that you gave to the 2nd question can't i change my class to a library and i refer it in the other project which is in the same solution? if so why i use reference? thanks to you all.

Comment: @modestandcutegirl: How would you inherit from a class without the compiler knowing where that class is defined? You *can't* change a class to a library - they're completely different concepts. A class library is one kind of assembly; a class is a *member* of an assembly.

Answer (score 0):

The project is a *self sufficent* compilable unit, that *has to compile* into the valid assembly file. That's why you need esplicitly specifiy which referencies **every** project needs in order to be able to compile *separately* from others.

There is no any *inheritance* concept on projects level.

Comment: thanks you. so since they are different projects i need to reference them for the compile.

Answer (score 0):

> 1) why we give reference to the other project? cant we just use inheritance?

This question makes no sense.  What does inheritance have to do with project references.  Can you elaborate?

> 2) after we give the reference by using the visual studio IDE why we have to add the project to the namespace system?

Because there's an inherent difference between an assembly referencing another assembly (which is what happens when you add a reference to the project) and the *language* knowing where to find a *class* which is what happens when you use the `using` directive in a file.

For example, suppose you create a class in your project called `TextBox`.  Then in another file you want to use that class.  How would the language know whether you are referring to your custom `TextBox` class or another one in a referenced assembly?  The answer to that question is *namespaces*.  By fully-qualifying the class name with its namespaces, you tell the compiler which class you're using.

The `using` directive is a way to specifying the namespace once per file instead of every time you use the class (or other classes in that namespace).  So if you need to reference your `TextBox` class multiple times within a single file, you wouldn't want to have to write this *every* time:

```
MyCodebase.MyAssembly.MyNamespace.MyOtherNamespace.SomethingElse.TextBox
```

Instead, you include a `using` directive of the entire namespace, so you only have to write this:

```
TextBox
```

Comment: thank you all. i learn a lot from all of your writings. for the 1st question to explain more. lets say we have a solution which uses more then one projects and i give reference to an another project so that i can refer to the project that the reference has been given. so that i can reach to the other project also. but why this way but not by inheriting or by making a library of the class that im imheriting and using the dll in the other project. since im new i may miss the concepts but i asked my question according to the shallow knowledge that i have had.

Comment: @modestandcutegirl: I still get the feeling that you're not understanding the term "inheritance" in this case.  In your project you would make reference to another assembly in order to use the code in that assembly. This reference can be a reference to a project in the current solution. It could also be a reference to a DLL file. I generally prefer the former because it makes better use of the IDE's functionality. But this may not be what you're asking. Can you give a more complete example in the question about how you're referencing code and maybe give an example of your proposed alternative?